# Secret file vault for iPhone and Mac?

Tags: applications, macos

Is there a simple encrypted file vault for iPhone **and** Mac that share the same content, w/o third party server?

This is the use-case: I have certain files (texts and images) that I want to be protected. On Mac, I can create encrypted disk and mount when I need the files. This works fine. However, what I want here is an app that works both on iPhone and Mac, since I want to use files on my iPhone as well. Preferably w/o third party, but if encrypted I allow using e.g. Dropbox etc.

Here is a scenario:

- I open this vault on Mac. Put some file in there. Close the vault.
- Things get synced
- On my iPhone, I open the same vault and there I can browse files.

There are many apps that do this, but they are either for Mac OR iPhone. I want a solution that works across the devices.

Note: I also considered the built-in Notes. But I can't upload my files (that are not just text).

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What problem are you trying to solve?  What OS are you using?  Please see [ask] for a guideline on asking questions that can get you good answers.  If you want a software recommendation, see [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important info that should be followed. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: @fsb done, please check.

Comment: Did you consider the built-in Notes ? Can carry text & pictures, encrypted password lock & syncs automatically across all devices.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, but I can't upload my files (that are not just text).

Answer (score 2):

[Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/) allows you to encrypt data stored in the usual clouds and access it from both Mac and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a third party server, then you need to look at open source solutions and host them on your own servers/platforms. Personally, I host [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com) on my own server and use their Mobile and Desktop apps to sync files from seamlessly.

You can also look into [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) (an older service from the creators of Nextcloud).

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am aware I can have a personal cloud, but I want an app that is also hiding files.

Comment: @ɹoƃı That makes no sense. What do you mean by "hide files". If you are hosting it on your own server, then you control the files. No one else can access them, both ownCloud and NextCloud require you to setup a login.